# Google Maps Javascript API Issue Drawing Multiple Circles

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I'm trying to draw multiple circles all with different centers and different radius's (radii?) using this code:

```
var citymap = {
     chicago: {
         loc : "Chicago, IL",
         center: {lat: 40, lng: -70},
         shootings: 140000
     },
     newyork: {
         loc : "New York, NY",
         center: {lat: 40, lng: -70},
         shootings: 80000
     },
     losangeles: {
        loc : "Los Angeles, CA",
        center: {lat: 40, lng: -70},
        shootings: 40000
     },
};

var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 39.14, lng: -98.1},
    zoom: 5
});

for (var city in citymap) {
    var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': citymap[city].loc}, 
          function(results, status) {
              citymap[city].center = { 
                  lat : results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                  lng : results[0].geometry.location.lng()
              }

              // Add the circle for this city to the map.
              var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                  strokeWeight: 2,
                  fillColor: '#FF0000',
                  fillOpacity: 0.5,
                  map: map,
                  center: citymap[city].center,
                  radius: citymap[city].shootings 
              });    
           }); 
    }
```

I feel like this should be working, but all the circles get drawn with the same radii. If I put cityCircle outside of the geocoder function, it then draws the circles with different radii but all on the same spot. Anyone know what the issue is here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchonous.  When the callback function runs, the loop has completed and `city` is left at the last value, so all the circles get the radius of the last entry.

One fix is to use function closure:

```
function createCircleFromGeocode(city) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': citymap[city].loc
  }, function(results, status) {
    citymap[city].center = {
      lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
      lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
    }
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: citymap[city].shootings
    });
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwp965sp/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 39.14,
      lng: -98.1
    },
    zoom: 3
  });

  for (var city in citymap) {
    createCircleFromGeocode(city);
  }
}

function createCircleFromGeocode(city) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': citymap[city].loc
  }, function(results, status) {
    citymap[city].center = {
      lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
      lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
    }

    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: citymap[city].shootings
    });

  });

}
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var citymap = {
  chicago: {
    loc: "Chicago, IL",
    center: {
      lat: 40,
      lng: -70
    },
    shootings: 140000

  },
  newyork: {
    loc: "New York, NY",
    center: {
      lat: 40,
      lng: -80
    },
    shootings: 80000
  },
  losangeles: {
    loc: "Los Angeles, CA",
    center: {
      lat: 40,
      lng: -100
    },
    shootings: 40000
  },

};
var map;


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for your help!